# I want text to change with a button. Can't put images or anything in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, button

I want to make a certain text changable with 2 buttons. This is what I have right now, this works fine. (Don't mind the language, I'm dutch)

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='NU WORDT HET ENGELS';">English</button> &#160; <button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='Nu terug nederlands';">Nederlands</button>

<div id="chgtext">Heb je een vraag, een idee voor een post die je graag op mijn blog zou willen zien, of een andere reden waarom je mij wilt contacteren. Stuur me dan e-mail op (Of klik in de sidebar op het<font color="white">-</font><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><font color="white">-</font>icoontje onder <em>social </em>)</div>
```

What I would like to do, is to put images and < font style,.... into the changing text. But I can't. I have already tried doing it with \' but it doesn't work either. This is another code I have, It works fine on the code snippet, but it does not work on my blog:

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='This is the default text. <img src=\'http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-50-50-6.jpg\'> with image <span style=\'color :red;\'>and color</span>';">English</button> &#160; <button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='Text changed into Another <span style=\'color :red;\'>language</span>';">Nederlands</button>

<div id="chgtext">This is the default text. </div>
```

this is what I get --> http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/2017/02/03/test-2/

The end result I need is this:

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='NU WORDT HET ENGELS';">English</button> &#160; <button onclick="document.getElementById('chgtext').innerHTML='Heb je een vraag, een idee voor een post die je graag op mijn blog zou willen zien, of een andere reden waarom je mij wilt contacteren. Stuur me dan e-mail op info@rosalea.be (Of klik in de sidebar op het<font color="white">-</font><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><font color="white">-</font>icoontje onder <em>social </em>)';">Nederlands</button>

<div id="chgtext">Heb je een vraag, een idee voor een post die je graag op mijn blog zou willen zien, of een andere reden waarom je mij wilt contacteren. Stuur me dan e-mail op info@rosalea.be (Of klik in de sidebar op het<font color="white">-</font><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><font color="white">-</font>icoontje onder <em>social </em>)</div>
```

But ofcourse that is not possible, How could I make this possible? (I don't have 2 text insert boxes for HTML AND CSS, I only have 1 box to put code in when creating a wordpress blog post

Comment: From looking at your output on your blog theres a few `‘`'s and `”`'s instead of `'`'s and `"`'s. The code you posted above works perfectly fine in a jsfiddle. Is a straight copy paste of that code being done to your blog?

Comment: Yes I copied it straight from my blog

Comment: @DanielRuxton I need to be able to put images in it, font styles to make titles between my text, and I want to use Font Awesome icons `</font><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>`

Comment: i see you have tagged jquery, there are some functions that could make some of the selection easier

Comment: @happymacarts I just took the 5 suggested tags :p I don't know the differences very well between css, jquery, html,... I'm a beginner in html/css :p. I know some of it, and I have tried some different codes to try to solve this problem but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: Take a look at my answer below and comment there if you need any additional help

Answer (score 2):

You may have had issues with `Escaping` the  quotes

for example when setting values in javascript you can use either single or double quotes

```
someVar = "a value"; // this works fine
someVar = 'a value';// this works too
someVar = "a value that's an issue";// will work
someVar = 'a value that's an issue';// but this one breaks
```

to solve that issue you can use a `\` to escape it like this

```
someVar = 'a value that\'s an issue';// now it works
```

I added your language as a `data-` attribute but could be done a s a class or even reading the button text itself if you wanted to.

I also separated your javascript into a document ready block that will keep all of your script logic separate from your display and make editing easier later (best practices) .

One resource that you will find incredible useful is the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Sometime WYSIWYG editors strip script and reformat some Quotes. you may have to change some settings in WP to accommodate your script elements inside of  a post

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        output = '';
        switch ($(this).data('lang')) {
          case 'English':
            output = 'This is the default text.'+
              '<img src=\'http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-50-50-6.jpg\'> with image <span class=\'red\'>and color</span><p>Do you have a question, an idea for a post you\'d like to see on my blog, or any other reason you want to contact me. please send me email at info@rosalea.be (Or, in the sidebar on the - icon under social)</p>';
            break;
          case 'Nederlands':
            output = 'Heb je een vraag, een idee voor een post die je graag op mijn blog zou willen zien, of een andere reden waarom je mij wilt contacteren. Stuur me dan e-mail op info@rosalea.be (Of klik in de sidebar op het<span class="white">-</span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="white">-</span>icoontje onder <em>social </em>)';
            break;
          default:
            output = 'This is the default text.';

        }
        $('#chgtext').html(output);
      })

    })
</script>
<div>
    <button class="btn" data-lang="English">English</button>
    <button class="btn" data-lang="Nederlands">Nederlands</button></div>

<div id="chgtext">This is the default text.</div>
```

```css
/* add these lines to your css file if you want */
.white{
  color:white;
}
.red{
  color:red;
}

/*these should be in your framework already */
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I modified the answer to provide more explanation. If you find the answer useful and it answered your question please accept it as the answer

Comment: I answered your answer below

Comment: I read your post below i think that your issue is the WYSIWYG editor. Sometimes the replace quotes strangely. btw you shouldn't anwer it that way just comment or change your original question

Comment: i put the first code in my post, and the css in the css but nothing happens when I click the buttons :s

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console? If you view the source of the rendered page is the code there? Once you save in WP and try to edit does the code disappear?

Comment: I'm trying my best to understand what you mean but I'm not sure what rednered page is, I put the first code as html in my post, then I put the css in 'add additional CSS'. And then I saved without any problem. When I go check test the buttons, they don't work. http://oihanevalbuenaredondo.be/2017/01/14/this-is-a-post-title/

This is actually the page i need the code for. I want to be able to write the post in 2 languages, that can be changed by clicking the buttons

Comment: I'm not an expert in css and html,... I know basic things to edit the theme of my whole blog, but i'm not good with the more complex stuff

Comment: the console is your browsers document inspector F12 in Chrome and most of them, then you go to the `Console` tab. The rendered html is the `Elements` tab